# How to find a branch which is analytic on the exterior of the unit circle for $\sqrt(z^2 +1)$, $|z| > 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, branch-cuts, multivalued-functions

I know we can rewrite $\sqrt{z^2 +1}$ as $z^2 (1+z^{-2})$ and use this by looking at the principal branch of the function $\exp{\left(\frac{1}{2} \log(1+z^{-2})\right)}$.

However I am struggling to find the domain of holomorphicity that includes the exterior of the unit disc.

I keep trying to find where $\exp(\frac{1}{2} \log(1+z^{-2})$ has cuts and see that it is when  $1+z^{-2}$ is negative real but I don't see how would relate to the unit circle as the value for $z$ I find is the complement of the interval $[-i,i]$.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: cut the segment from $[-i,i]$ on the imaginary axis and see how the argument of $z^2+1$ behaves if it's $\pi$ on the negative axis (start at zero on the positive axis, then approaching the positive imaginary axis above $i, z^2+1$ crosses the negative reals, so the argument crosses through $\pi$, then you go towards the negative reals, the argument crosses through $2\pi$ etc, so back at the reals you get $4\pi$ -so you cannot define $\log(z^2+1)$ continuously, but you just need $\sqrt {z^2+1}$ and that works as at the reals you get back the positive branch of the square root by the above

Comment: so for example $\sqrt {a^2+1}$ is the usual one for $a >0$, so $f(2)=\sqrt {2^2+1}=\sqrt 5$ then $f(2i)=\sqrt {(2i)^2+1}=i\sqrt 3$, then $f(-2)=\sqrt {(-2)^2+1}=-\sqrt 5$ and finally $f(-2i)=\sqrt {(-2i)^2+1}=-i \sqrt 3$ where the RHS square roots are the standard ones for positive numbers

Comment: Branch cuts are not set in stone. They are to some extent something you can choose to fit your problem. The cuts "anchor" at singularities, but can get from one singularity to another by any simple path. In this case, the simplest path is the line segment connecting the singularities at $-i$ and $i$. But if you need to work around $0$, you could instead cut it along $i \cdot [1, \infty)$ and $-i \cdot [1,\infty)$. Or you could cut it in a semi-circle between the two singularities.